# ld.exe: final link failed: Memory exhausted while building qt

Tags: qt, gcc, compilation, linker

finally I've compiled qt from source,by using:
configure in qt's source folder, and then running mingw32-make.
But now I'm getting following error:
ld.exe: final link failed: Memory exhausted
I have 4GB ram, 1.3TB hard drive. How on earth is this possible. How shall I fix this problem so I can link those object files?

Comment: What build options are you using? What compiler version? Are you trying to use LTO?

Comment: @I'm using default options which is as I've listed: configure in qt source directory and after configure is finished mingw32-make. What is LTO?

Comment: Ok, LTO is link time optimization.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what default options QT uses.

Comment: #ams that's ok, it went through with -lto, thanks. +1